# Watir-webdriver is progressing through script before Nokogiri finishes scraping

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, watir, watir-webdriver

There are three forms on the page. All forms default to "today" for their date ranges. Each form is iteratively submitted with a date from a range (1/1/2013 - 1/3/2013, for example) and the resulting table is scraped.

The script then submit the date to the next form in line and again, the table is scraped. However, the scraping is occurring before the dates are submitted.

I tried adding `sleep 2` in between scrapes to no avail.

The script is here: https://gist.github.com/hnanon/de4801e460a31d93bbdc

Comment: You should probably be using mechanize for this. Otherwise timing browser dom elements coming in and out of visibility can drive you crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script appears to assume that Nokogiri and Watir will always be in sync. This is not correct.

When you do:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
```

Nokogiri gets the browser html at that one specific point in time. If Watir makes a change to the browser (ie changes the html), Nokogiri will not know about it.

Each time you want to parse the html with Nokogiri, you need to create a new Nokogiri object using the browser's latest html.

An example to illustrate:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'

b = Watir::Browser.new

b.goto 'www.google.ca'
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(b.html)
p page
#=> This will be the Google page

b.goto 'www.yahoo.ca'
p page
#=> This will still be the Google page

page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(b.html)
p page
#=> This will now be the Yahoo page
```

Comment: I just tried that and the same thing is happening. I put `page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(b.html)` before the start of each scrape. I updated the script so you can see too.

Comment: It is still in the incorrect spot. It needs to be done _after_ you change the page's html but before you convert the table to a hash. Move it to after you generate the report (ie after `btn.click`).

Comment: I tried that. Still not working. It just seems to want to scrape the other tables too. Here's what the script is writing to the terminal: https://gist.github.com/hnanon/22814cb5584f876f3247

Comment: You probably need to move the `hours_table`, `wage_table`, etc to be retrieved for the correct Nokogiri page object. For your output, you should add a output for each hash created (just to see which ones are failing).

Comment: Those tables were moved to be just under their respective `page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(b.html)`. I printed the output for each hash. Nothing is displayed for Hours (as it should be; all values are empty), but I'm still getting values for Activations and Revenue (they too should be empty). See updated script and terminal output gists. Sorry to keep bugging you.

Comment: They are still incorrect. For example, at line 28, you are getting the wage_table, yet at the line 33 you are scraping the hours_table. Line 28 should be getting the hours table, which is incorrectly up at line 14.

Comment: That did it. I'm trying it now with a true date range (I had it set to `(Date.new(2013, 01, 01)..Date.new(2013, 01, 01)).each do |date|`. You're awesome.

Comment: It seems to occasionally still scrape data in advance. Any other ideas?

Comment: Strange. It's scraping data from another table (with a different ID!) and only one row at that.

Comment: It's working again...sorry. I had `hours_table` in the wrong place. The script was incorrectly parsing the first table on the page until I moved it to the correct line.